# How do I get a specific string using ps command in linux

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

For instance, consider the following example. I have a process running on my machine and I only want a specific string in my output. 

When I run the following command 
ps -ef | grep pmon

I get
oracle    3680     1  0 Oct04 ?  00:00:08 ora_pmon_SEED

I want the command to only display "SEED"
SEED

Comment: You may have `pgrep` on your system that can replace `ps | grep`

Comment: ps -ef | awk -F_ '/[p]mon/{print $NF}'

Comment: @Kamaraj - Thanks. Yes, your command worked too. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that **specific** example you could pipe it through to `cut`:

```
ps -ef | grep pmon | cut -d _ -f 3
```

Why you would want to, however, is a bit of a mystery.

Comment: I'm trying to grep for all active oracle instances on my servers.